# Dropdown Menu with -90deg menubar

Tags: html, css

I have a -90deg menu bar, the clickable buttons are also -90deg.. I am wondering if there is anyway I can add a dropdown menu to one of my buttons , test5/nth-child(5) is the one I would like to add a dropdown menu to, if possible I would appreciate it, if its possible to do the dropdown at -90deg that would be great, if not i can deal with horizontal that will also work great  , Thanks Again

https://jsfiddle.net/nyjhfr8g/2/

CSS -

```
body {
  font-family:Verdana,Geneva,sans-serif;
  color:#FFF;
  font-size:12px;
  font-family:Trebuchet MS,Arial,Helvetica;
  text-align:center;
  background:url() no-repeat center 0,#000 url() left top;
  background-size:1670px 950px;
}

p {
  margin-bottom:10px;
  line-height:21px;
}

a {
  color:#F09;
  text-decoration:none;
}

a:hover {
  text-decoration:underline;
}

#right_menu {
  position:fixed;
  font-size:15px;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  background-color:#FF00FF;
  width:50px;
  height:100%;
}

#right_menu a {
  text-align:center;
  display:block;
  padding:10px;
  height:15%;
  width:50px;
  margin-bottom:0;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  position:relative;
}

#right_menu a:nth-child(1) {
  background-color:#FF00FF;
  color:#FFF;
}

#right_menu a:nth-child(1) span {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:40px;
  left:-40px;
  width:130px;
  color:#FFF;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  transition:left .3s ease;
}

#right_menu a:nth-child(1):hover span {
  left:-45px;
}

#right_menu a:nth-child(2) {
  background-color:#FF00FF;
  color:#FFF;
}

#right_menu a:nth-child(2) span {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:-40px;
  width:130px;
  color:#FFF;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  transition:left .3s ease;
}

#right_menu a:nth-child(2):hover span {
  left:-45px;
}

#right_menu a:nth-child(3) {
  background-color:#FF00FF;
  color:#FFF;
}

#right_menu a:nth-child(3) span {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:-40px;
  width:130px;
  color:#FFF;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  transition:left .3s ease;
}

#right_menu a:nth-child(3):hover span {
  left:-45px;
}

#right_menu a:nth-child(4) {
  background-color:#FF00FF;
  color:#FFF;
}

#right_menu a:nth-child(4) span {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:-40px;
  width:130px;
  color:#FFF;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  transition:left .3s ease;
}

#right_menu a:nth-child(4):hover span {
  left:-45px;
}

#right_menu a:nth-child(5) {
  background-color:#FF00FF;
  color:#FFF;
}

#right_menu a:nth-child(5) span {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:-40px;
  width:130px;
  color:#FFF;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  transition:left .3s ease;
}

#right_menu a:nth-child(5):hover span {
  left:-45px;
}

#right_menu a:nth-child(6) {
  background-color:#FF00FF;
  color:#FFF;
}

#right_menu a:nth-child(6) span {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:-40px;
  width:130px;
  color:#FFF;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  transition:left .3s ease;
}

#right_menu a:nth-child(6):hover span {
  left:-45px;
}
```

HTML -

```
<div id="right_menu">
    <a href="#testing1"><span>testing</span></a>
    <a href="#testing2"><span>testing</span></a>
    <a href="#testing3"><span>testing</span></a>
    <a href="#testing4"><span>testing</span></a>
    <a href="#testing5"><span>Drop MENU</span></a>
    <a href="#testing6"><span>testing</span></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80470/discussion-on-question-by-v-josh-c-dropdown-menu-with-90deg-menubar).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK...not perfect but I think I have it down enough so you can tweak to suit your requirements.

The first thing is to use a wrapper to hold the menu..in this case, I've used a `nav`. What this allows us to do is build the menu as normal but transform the wrapper `nav` to position the whole thing as we want.

So.

This is our structure :

```
<nav>
  <ul id="right_menu">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 2</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 3</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 4</a>
      <ul class="sub_menu">
        <li><a href="">Sub-item 1</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Sub-item 2</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="">Sub-item 3</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Item 5</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Then we position the `nav` so that it's fixed to the top / right **but** we then rotate it 90 degrees (actually -90 degrees). To adjust the point at which the nav rotates we use `transform-origin` and a small `translateX` equal to the height of the `nav`

```
nav {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: #FF00FF;
  position: fixed;
  top:50;
  right:0;
  width: 100vh; /* I'm always the height (after rotation) of the viewport */
  transform-origin:top right;
  transform:translateX(-50px) rotate(-90deg);
}
```

So, now we have the nav in the right place but the menu itself would have the wrong order.

We solve that by floating the list-items to the right and so they are now reverse and the first one is now at the top of the rotated menu.

```
#right_menu > li {
    float: right;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    position: relative;
    color:white;
    list-style:none;
}
```

OK...first level done.

Second level is another `ul` but we position it absolutely

```
.sub_menu {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top:-100%; /* now to the "left" of the parent */
  left:50%;
  transform:translateX(-50%); /* center it over the parent */
  width: auto;
  white-space: nowrap; /* allows the sub menu to be wider than parent */
}
```

[**Final Result Codepen**](http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/EjXddY)

**Note:** I've restricted myself to the positioning...I'm not sure everything else is there yet but I think the basics are there.

Comment: I don't know what you had meant by *not appropriate structure* but I find this answer pretty good :)

Comment: What I meant was that links don't have submenus...they're links...it's not really logical. Use divs maybe...but the `ul/li/ul` *standard* structure is **ideal** for what is being attempted here.

Comment: Fair enough, got you :)

Comment: @Paulie_D hey bro is there any way you can check out this problem im having the link to the question is here 
[S-O-F Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30928894/submenu-not-positioning-exactly-side-by-side/30929552?noredirect=1#comment50138971_30929552)