# Menu Bar only works using nth-child (1) span

Tags: html, css

i have a -90deg menubar with a submenu that will only work using this code
my question is can we get example1 on codepen , to work with example 2 from jsfiddle using nth-child, this way i can make a submenu using nth-child(4)
Thanks for any help in advance, btw you can ignore the codes, everything is shown in codepen , and jsfiddle

css

```
nav {
  height: 50px;
  line-height: 50px;
  background: #FF00FF;
  position: fixed;
  top:50;
  right:0;
  width: 100vh;
  transform-origin:top right;
  transform:translateX(-50px) rotate(-90deg);
}
```

http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/EjXddY

but the issue is this info will not work on the site that im trying to get it to work on , only this code will work on the site.

css

```
#right_menu a:nth-child(1) span {
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:40px;
  left:-40px;
  width:130px;
  color:#FFF;
  -webkit-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  -moz-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  -ms-transform:rotate(-90deg);
  transition:left .3s ease;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nyjhfr8g/2/

Comment: Can you explain your problem a bit more clearly? What is not working? I don't find any sub menu at all in your fiddle.

Comment: The original question **[HERE**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30802304/dropdown-menu-with-90deg-menubar/30804216#30804216). The original structure just isn't appropriate for a menu/submenu structure. That's why I abandoned it. so You're *comparing apples and oranges.* By the way...the original question seemed to be for a different SO user/account.

Comment: ohh i logged in an old account from a while back i thought i lost it, anyway i was reposting this question because you stopped talking to me about it and i still needed help, your answer with codepen was perfect , the only issue is it doesn't work on where im trying to get it to work, i have no clue why , don't ask me but everything stacks each other on the site, as well it don't work on jsfiddle.. but on the site they all stack, and that is why i was using nth-child to separate each button individually so they will all show.. i even tried giving you the site so you could see the issue

Comment: @Harry   the sub menu is on Codepen from example 1 , which doesn't work on example 2 on jsfiddle

Comment: What I'm trying to say is that your JSFiddle version **isn't** appropriate (IMO) for what you are trying to do. I answered your question which you accepted. With the greatest respect, you then ignored what I gave you and then wanted, it seemed, for me to guide you through applying it to something that clearly didn't work.

Comment: @joshua : If you don't have the sub-menu elements in the HTML, how do you expect them to magically appear in the fiddle? The Codepen example has those children elements (and the menu is properly structured / adapted to have multiple levels). You should change your menu structure to what Paulie_D showed you.

Comment: @Billy  i tried many ways to use his , also applying his html into mine combining both css / html and i can't seem to get it to view on my webpage, his example in codepen is perfect, my question if you re read was if there was anyway to combine both to make it work using nth-child as presented in jsfiddle,and yes Paulie_D  i appreciate your time and effort in doing what you did, and i accepted it with no hesitation because you did exactly what i wanted, but it came out that it wouldn't work on my webpage,therefor i asked if there was any other way to come about it, if not i appreciate the time

Comment: But why can't you just convert your links into `ul` list? That makes your CSS code shorter and easier to manage. You won't even need to use nth-child for your sub-menu. If you can add the sub-menu to the fiddle or show us your webpage, that would be good. Otherwise we have no idea what your problem is because there's only 1 level of menu in both your HTML and CSS. If you are using the exact same code on your webpage, then it's obvious that you don't have 2nd level menu, that's why there's no sub-menu.

Comment: @Billy  the reason i can't is because the site has its own main frame to handle that, i can't go in and change that.. my site is   
profiles.myfreecams.com/testing99x     i am doing this for a friend and its kind of complicated the way it works , it is a site 21+ so you might get offended , just a heads up