# submenu not positioning exactly side-by-side

Tags: html, css

I found an issue with `.sub_menu` code `left:-;` and `transform:translateX(-%);`,So I changed position to relative and re-positioned with the two codes above, It seemed to work but now the two sub menus i have are no longer Side-By-Side. What they do is separate by a few centimeters top:, Not sure what made this happen, Any help would be appreciated,Thanks

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b92txask/1/) sub menu pops up when you hover over Gallery

```
.sub_menu {
  display: none;
  position:relative;
  top:-60%;
  left:-350%;
  transform:translateX(-40%);
  width: auto;
}

.sub_menu > li {
  display:inline-block;
}

.sub_menu li a {
  background:-webkit-linear-gradient(#77047e,#FF00FF);
  background:-o-linear-gradient(#77047e,#FF00FF);
  background:-moz-linear-gradient(#77047e,#FF00FF);
  background:linear-gradient(#77047e,#FF00FF);
}

.sub_menu li a:hover {
  background:#FF00FF;
  top:1em;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand at taking a quick look is the `sub.menu`s are odd. They currently have the style `position: absolute`, and that would make them all align in the same exact place. As you can see you are doing that here:

```
.sub_menu {
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:-37%;
  left:-47%;
  transform:translateX(-20%);
  width:auto;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

So instead a fix would most likely be using `position: relative`, and then aligning them from there. Also when working with a sub menu, it would help to have an ID on each element to align it correctly (Especially when aligning them vertically and horizontally).

Comment: ok well it seemed to work now that i played around with the code a little, but there is another issue that happened after changing it to `position:relative;`, i have updated the code with JSFiddle and updated my question if you think you might be able to help . Thanks

Comment: Hello @V_JOSH_C, could you please explain the issue a little bit to me and explain what you would like to happen! :)

Comment: click on the JSFiddle, hover mouse over Gallery and take a look at the submenu , you will see how they are not even. they are separated by a few centimeters top: idk why, i would like them to be even. This happened when I changed `position:abosolute;` to `position:relative;`